# SQL statement not working

Tags: sql, postgresql

how to do an sql statement like this one that actually works:

```
select distinct store_id as myid, 
       (select count(*) from products where store_id = myid and delete_flag = true)     
from products 
where delete_flag = true
```

I want a column with every store id and the number of deleted products with this store id.

Comment: Is it mysql or postgresql?

Comment: In this case i would go with JOIN and not subquery in the SELECT clause..

Answer (score 3):

```
select store_id, 
       count(*) as all_product_count,
       sum(case when delete_flag = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as deleted_product_count
from products     
group by store_id
```

Comment: "I want a column with every store id and the number of deleted products with this store id" if no product is deleted than it will show 0 thats what i think OP needs

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps!

```
select store_id as myid , count(*) as noofdeleteditems from products where delete_flag = true group by store_id;
```